# Esri Oceans Basemap fullwidth

Tags: openlayers, mapcontrol

I am using in my project the Esri Ocean Basemap. I use the fullscreen control to enlarge it, but when enabled the map is not covering the whole screen.

The HTML structure is as follows:

```
<div id="full-size-container-custom" class="full-size-container-custom">
 <div class="map-container">
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="sidebar-map-container" class="sidebar-map"></div>
</div>
```

The controls are loaded as

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [],
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        new ol.control.Zoom(),
        new ol.control.Attribution(),
        new ol.control.ZoomSlider(),
        new ol.control.MousePosition({
          projection: mercatorProjection,
            coordinateFormat: function (coordinate) {
                return 'Coordinates: ' + 'Lat ' + ol.coordinate.format(coordinate, '{y}', 3) + ' Long ' + ol.coordinate.format(coordinate, '{x}', 3);
            },
            target: 'coordinates'
        }), 
        new ol.control.ScaleLine(),
        new ol.control.FullScreen({source:'full-size-container-custom'}),
        new app.Legend()
    ]),
    view: view
```

And the CSS is

```
.full-size-container-custom {
margin-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}
.full-size-container-custom:-moz-full-screen {
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.full-size-container-custom:-webkit-full-screen {
  height: 100%;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.full-size-container-custom:-ms-fullscreen {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
 }
.full-size-container-custom:-fullscreen {
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #fff;
}
map-container {
height:100%;
width: 80%;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
float:left;
}
.sidebar-map {
width: 19%;
height:100%;
padding: 0 0 0 1%;
float:left;
}
.map{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.map {
position: relative;
}
```

The aspect of the map can be seen in the following two screenshots. Do you have any suggestion?

Map in normal view
[image: Map in normal view]

Map in fulscreen
[image: Map in fulscreen]

Comment: That looks very similar to the behaviour of the OpenLayers 5 example https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/full-screen-source.html if you zoom out the view before going to full screen the resolution does not change when it becomes full screen.  In OpenLayers 6 https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/full-screen-source.html a view using a global projection has a default `multiWorld: false` constraint which prevents more than one world being visible.

Comment: Yes Mike I used the same code of the example you mentioned (I am using OL 4 by the way). However it doesn't behave as it should. I am not sure if this is a problem related to the Esri Ocean Basemap or to some part of the code I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any different in how your code behaves and how the OpenLayers 4/5 examples behave - the resolution does not change when the map size changes, so you may have some empty space above and below the 85 degree latitudes which are the limit of the web mercator  projection.

To get closer to the way the Openlayers 6 example behaves you could calculate a minimum zoom level needed to fit the map height when the map size changes

```
map.on('change:size', function() {
  var maxRes = ol.extent.getHeight(map.getView().getProjection().getExtent())/map.getSize()[1];
  map.getView().setMinZoom(map.getView().getZoomForResolution(maxRes));
});
```

Comment: I tried it, but the line `map.getView().setMinZoom(map.getView().getZoomForResolution(maxRes));` turns out with **map.getView().getZoomForResolution is not a function** message

Comment: It works with version 4.6.5 https://jsfiddle.net/n6rqc89m/

Comment: You are right. I forgot to update the ol.js to 4.6.5! Fantastic thanks